# ASCII FBX Files

Tags: import

I have some FBX files, (without the program they were made on), and according to the error message when I import them to blender, they are ASCII FBX files. I need to convert them to binary FBX files (or anything else, .obj, .dae) to import them into blender. Any way/tools in which I could do this? I have seen several links to the autodesk tool that converts them however they all just bring me to the autodesk front page. 
    If anybody has a direct download link to that tool or any other method to convert these ASCII FBX files to anything else, please let me know. Thanks!

I am using blender v 2.79 on MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: Afaik the simplest way to do this is to use their FBX Converter tool available now via archive https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/fbx-converter-archives. Blender itself can only export ASCII from certain time

Comment: @MrZak You should submit this as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Wait, no need for downloads

If you have a Windows 10 computer as well you can convert it on that using 3D viewer to export it to .glb that can be opened in Blender. 
If you ever get a Windows 10 PC use it to convert .FBX files.

Comment: Wow, what a nice trick! But what about animation files like `Sheep@Idle.fbx`?

Answer (score 1):

What really works is this:
https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/fbx-sdk-2020-0?us_oa=akn-us&us_si=9066be5d-863a-4cd3-b98f-87bda034316b&us_st=fbx%20sdk

there you can download sdk for all common used os.

You can compile the ConvertScene sample with: cmake, gcc, libxml2-dev

The resulting binary can be used to convert ascii fbx to bin fbx that can be imported in blender.

Comment: There is a newer version here: https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/fbx-sdk-2020-3

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could try an online resource such as https://anyconv.com/fbx-to-glb-converter/ which can convert the original ASCII .fbx file to a .glb or .obj or .stl file suitable for Blender which can in turn export as a binary fbx.